# How to manage styling using JS in React?

Tags: reactjs

We are developing an application in React which has components like Input, Select, Accordion etc which can be re-used in a lot of other projects in our organisation to maintain a consistency.

We are using Material-UI styles to style our components using Javascript rather than CSS so that when other developers reuse the components they don't override the existing styling with CSS.

However, we have realised that the build time is long and when the components will be re-used in all the other projects,they will have a dependency on Material-UI which we don't want.

Can you guys please suggest on what is the best approach to maintain such application which can be re-used elsewhere and the best way to maintain the styles?

Comment: That's the trade-off for using React :/

Comment: Write your own component library, use storybook

Comment: @DennisVash - Isn't that a similar approach to Material-ui?

Comment: We use a styling system similar to material ui, i.e. styled components.

Comment: You will always be dependent on a third party library if you don't use plain CSS or React-Styles. The tradeoffs of using CSS in Vanilla, Scss or Less is clear. React-Styles they are applied as slower  inline css attributes of the DOM.

I would recommend a system similar to Material-UI or Styled Components.
I would choose the system with the biggest community.
current weekly npm downloads
styled-components: 1200000<
material-ui: 710000<